# XSLT failing for unknown reason on xsl:value-of

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to create an xslt template, but it keeps silently failing like as if an exception is happening but is not being caught.  The closing  bracket is not being written out, invalidating the output;

the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gallery>
    <item>
        <file>IMAGEHEADER1.jpg</file>
        <thelink>michaeljackson123.htm</thelink>
    </item>
    <item>
        <file>IMAGEHEADER2.jpg</file>
        <thelink>barrywhite456.htm</thelink>
    </item>
</gallery>
```

XSLT File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="gallery">
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                    <td rowspan="2" height="122" width="510">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                    </td>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <a style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px" id="categorylink">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="thelink"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="file" />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="file">
        <img alt="">
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Invalid output, missing the closing tab.

```
<html>
<body>
<tr>1<td rowspan="2" height="122" width="510"><a style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px" id="categorylink" href="michaeljackson123.htm"><img alt="" src="IMAGEHEADER1.jpg"></a></td>2</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

My expected output is;

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>1
                <td rowspan="2" height="122" width="510">
                    <a style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px" id="categorylink" href="michaeljackson123.htm">
                        <img alt="" src="IMAGEHEADER1.jpg"></img>
                    </a>
                </td>2
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help, can't see why it's failing.

Comment: What is the expected output? (btw - you should wrap those `tr` tags with `table` tags).

Comment: My expected output is the actual output plus a closing </img> tag, really confused as to why it's failing.

Comment: Added an example of the output I would like.  :-)

Comment: @Wonea: Which XSLT implementation are you using?

Comment: Its unclear by your post what error you are referring to.  There are many issues with the output, the most obvious being the use of <tr> and <td> not being wrapped in the <table> tag.  Also Dave pointed out the non terminated <img> tag.  I am not sure what your question is - I ran the xslt transform and it runs with no issues.  I think you might want to use a tool to validate the html output if you are unsure what is valid or not - you can use something like http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about missing the "closing tab" or "closing bracket". The output you showed seems to have all its end tags, so it's well-formed (if not valid). Do you mean the `<img>` lacks the self-closing slash? That's OK in html I believe.

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question with your template updates.

Comment: @wonea, your question would have been easier to answer if you'd used correct terminology. The `</img>` is a closing *tag* rather than *tab*, and it's not a closing bracket... the closing angle bracket is just `>`. Also the output was not "invalid" (HTML) because of the lack of closing tag... rather it was "not-well-formed" XML because of the lack of closing tag. If a downstream program was complaining about the lack of `</img>`, that should be stated as part of how you knew there was a "failure".

Comment: Agreed, my terminology needs brushing up.  Alejandro answered my question, by changing the XSLT output type.  Okay, I'm working with HTML is a very strict sense, as I'm putting my HTML files through an XML reader at a later stage, so it's very important they are from a markup document point of view, valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the differences between HTML and XML serialization:

Your stylesheet defaults to HTML serialization because your root element is `html`. In this case, all DTD declared empty elements are output the way it's suppose:

```
<img alt="" src="IMAGEHEADER1.jpg">
```

If you want an XML serialization, you should declare:

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
```

Then your output will be:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>1
                <td rowspan="2" height="122" width="510">
                    <a style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px" id="categorylink" href="michaeljackson123.htm">
                        <img alt="" src="IMAGEHEADER1.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </td>2
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. I believe this is a case where "failing" meant that the user's expectations were just not aligned with specified behavior. That's why it's so important for askers to state clearly what they expected.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say try adding an:

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
```

I think what is happening is that your serialization method is in auto mode, when it sees the html element in the default (not xhtml) namespace it is defaulting to html serialization, in which it is not required to close empty tags.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  As a side note it's strange how a strict HTML form is not observed when it could be easily produced.

Answer (score 1):

How are you viewing the output?  The closing tag on an img element is not required in HTML so if you are looking at it in a web browser, a lot of times the browser will display something slightly different than its literal input.  I've at least noticed this with firebug/chrome debugger.

Comment: I'm viewing it using the Marrorsoft Xselerator application, there is just a window outputting the raw text.